# Second url parameter is returning php error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

There is no problem when I enter the first parameter but when I enter the second parameter I get the error I mentioned below

[image: routes.php some parth]

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|resources|robots\\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I enter this url: `www.domain.com/first-parameter/second-parameter`

Returned Error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function base_url()

Filename: _inc/_head.php

Line Number: 4

Backtrace:
```

Comment: are you loading the url helper?

Comment: Yes automatically loading

Comment: Please edit your question with c/p code from image.

Comment: Can you show us a typical controller where this occurs as you describe. The fact that your controllers index methods work and any other methods do not work kind of hints that you do not use those views in your index methods. So it's be interesting to see what you are actually using.

Comment: show your url making this error

Comment: Throw it down in response to your request please do not look up english is not very good as far as i understand what i want

Answer (score 0):

routes.php

```
/*Ayarlar*/
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
/*Ayarlar*/
$route['(:any)'] = 'Home/index/$1';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = true;
```

I enter this url: www.domain.com/first-parameter/second-parameter

Example Local Url: http://localhost/sicacik-yemek-tarifleri-mobile/bilgi/assadad/asasad

controllers/Home.php

```
class Home extends public_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index($s1='')
{

    if(!empty($s1)){

        if (!empty($data['anakategori'])) {
            $this->load->view('example',$data);
        } elseif (!empty($data['altkategori'])) {
            $this->load->view('example',$data);
        }elseif(!empty($data['tarif'])){
            $this->load->view('example',$data);
        } elseif(!empty($kacKalori)){
            $this->load->view('example',$data);
        }else{
            show_404();
        }

    }else{
        $this->load->view('Home',$data);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't post images instead of code. Code is used to be copied finding solution in more convinient/easier way.

First this (Important in RED on user guide):

> The reserved routes must come before any wildcard or regular expression routes.

so your `$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = true;` has to be in different place.
Check [default file](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/routes.php) to determine where to put it.

Also,

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

so you have to reorder last two

```
$route['soru-cevap/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'soru_cevap/index/$1/$2'; //this one is more specific one
$route['soru-cevap/(:any)'] = 'soru_cevap/index/$1';

//Take a look of controller and method names. 
//Ones with dashes probably won't work.
```

Comment: I made the edits you said, but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to include $route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Home/index/$1/$2'; line in route.php

For www.domain.com/first-parameter/second-parameter url.